# How can I edit this question and start the reopening process to make additional answers possible?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

[dog-leg, dogleg, or dog leg?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/387446/217285) has one well-received and *currently* accepted answer but was quickly closed for lack of research. It was only my second question here, over three years ago now.

I'd accepted the answer after the question was closed, the possibility of other answers having been blocked by the closure.

To the comment "What do dictionaries say" I'd replied, but I didn't realize that responding quickly in comments was insufficient and that I was required to report what "dictionaries say" in the question itself to prevent closing.

Of course now if I follow the close reason instructions "Please include the research you’ve done..." it would be awkward because it could appear to be copying information from an answer back into a question, or changing the question after an answer was posted.

However keeping the question closed *blocks the entire community from posting any additional answers.* While closing may have seemed punitive at the time, or a way to encourage editing the question, it is now having the effect of preventing answers.

I'd like to allow for the possibility of additional answers, but I'm uncertain how I can modify the question in such a way as to still be fair to the existing answer. How might I proceed?

Granted someone may argue that the existing answer is "perfect" and no additional answers are possible, but we don't know that yet. Reopening the question offers an opportunity to see if a better or at least supplementary answer is possible.

Comment: The Wikipedia link doesn't lead to Wikipedia but to a question of yours on a different SE site. Fix that and I'll cast a reopen vote. The question has more than enough research.

Comment: BTW  I agree with Peter Shore's answer, I don't think anyone could improve on that.

Comment: You should probably explain why the current accepted  post doesn’t answer your question in full. What sort of information are you still looking for?

Comment: @user121863 Based on that logic, one could ask why accepting an answer doesn't automatically close a question. We of course don't do that because it's impossible to know if a better answer will be posted in the future. It's a core principle of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well, what is generally understood by accepting an answer is that the OP is saying “that’s what I was looking for”. It doesn’t mean that the question is “closed” but users are probably less motivated to add new answers.

Comment: @user121863 and clicking again on the same button un-accepts, because there can always be a better answer. It's just that closing a question prevents that answer from being posted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA done, thank you for catching that!

Comment: Plus, it looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: @user121863 if its a duplicate then it must be reopened because it is better to be closed as a duplicate properly in order to bring future readers to the "better" answer.

Comment: The fixed Wikipedia link does a good job of saying which article is most pertinent. I don't understand where or how "dog leg" could be a spelling variant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "dog leg" returns widespread usage as a proper noun, that may be where I've seen it. Search "Dog Leg Park". It turns out though that in the case of SpaceX they have named it "Dogleg Park". Actually, come to think of it, that would be a great additional answer to post, but answer posting is currently impossible...

Comment: I won't cast a reopen vote  because the Wikipedia link actually confirms that the word you needed is a solid compound (not hyphenated). I don't see any controversy nor ambiguity. I don't see how anyone could post an answer suggesting "dog leg" is acceptable without getting downvoted to the earth's core. If this had been posted on ELL I would have upvoted and voted to keep open but on EL&U we expect users to have done a minimum of research and *not* to have found the answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA okay thank you for your discussion and help!

Comment: I'm upvoting because a user who edits their closed question is probably seeking to reopen it but when a closed post is older than [70 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), it does not automatically enter the reopen queue (I think it should, regardless of how much time has passed). Your best bet is for someone to cast a reopen vote as “*a reopen vote will add a question to the reopen queue*”.